# named parameters Console.WriteLine c#

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I frequently write a Console.WriteLine statement and then modify it at a later stage. I then end up with statements such as this.

```
Console.WriteLine("{2} is not greater than {0} or smaller than {1}",min,max, grade);
```

Is there a way to explicitly name the parameters being passed to the Console.WriteLine, so that I do not need to pass min, max and grade in the order?

As a related note, I often remove variables to be printed in Console.WriteLine, such as below, where {2} has been removed.

```
Console.WriteLine("{3} is not greater than {0} or smaller than {1}",min,max, grade);
```

Is there a way to not change the numbering and say something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("{3} is not greater than {0} or smaller than {1}",{0}:min,{1}:max, {3}: grade);
```

in a similar way to statements like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your profile", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" });
```

Comment: Use C# 6 string interpolation: `$"{grade} is not greater..."`.

Comment: Why not use string interpolations ? $"{grade} is not greater than {min} or smaller than {max}"

Comment: Note that there is no auto completion in string.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{3} is not greater than {0} or smaller than {1}",min,max, grade);
```

You could also use C# 6 string interpolation syntax:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{grade} is not greater than {min} or smaller than {max}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can now put in strings like this

```
Console.WriteLine($"{grade} is not greater than {max} or smaller than {min}");
```

Note the $ sign in front of the string.